# How to set multiple values on form?

Tags: angular, typescript

I know that if I want to set a value on a field I can either use

> setValue

or

> patchValue

However, I'm facing this issue where I don't want to set value on each field **one by one**.

Here's my code for my form:

```
registrationForm = this._fb.group({
 firstName: ['', Validators.required],
 lastName: [''],
 age: [''],
 country: ['', Validators.required],
 hobby: [''],
 sport: [''],
 status: [''],
 country: ['', Validators.required],
 ...
 ...
});
```

I have an object called **person** that has all of those properties, so in order to set the values I'm doing this (**it works**), but I want to find a **BETTER** way of doing this:

```
registrationForm = this._fb.group({
 firstName: [this.person.firstName, Validators.required],
 lastName: [this.person.lastName],
 age: [this.person.age],
 country: [this.person.country, Validators.required],
 hobby: [this.person.hobby],
 sport: [this.person.sport],
 status: [this.person.status],
 country: [this.person.country, Validators.required],
 ...
 ...
});
```

Another way I'm thinking is by creating an object from person object so that I can use either setValue or patchValue. Something like:

```
 Object
 .keys(dataObject)
 .map((key) => {
 return { firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName, age: age ...}
 });
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: use ngModel where you don't have to assign value individually.

Comment: @AnuraagDJain can you provide an example? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know for a fact that the `person` object matches the properties of your form, you can just use `setValue` for the whole form with the `person`:

```
this.myFormGroup.setValue(this.person);
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fuyfdt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)**

---

EDIT: If you have other properties in your `person` object, properties that are not in your form, then you just use `patchValue()` instead, that takes the properties that matches the form:

```
this.myFormGroup.patchValue(this.person);
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xtbbcx?file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

Comment: Yes the properties match, but the problem with your solution is that person object has lots of properties that I don't need to set on my form. I only need to set the ones on my example. Any ideas how to approach this solution? Thanks

Comment: @progx Then use patchValue instead. Check updated answer :)

Comment: when using patchValue you are just setting that fields that are needed? also, is patchValue going to keep the validators that are already on each field or it will remove the validators?

Comment: Yes, with setvalue, every formcontrol needs to be set. So having extra or not all properties will throw error. With patchValue you can of course also set all form values, or just a few, or just read the properties you need, like we are doing here. With setValue and patchValue we are just modifying the values, so all the validators will stay in place :)

Comment: Thanks a lot bro!